# Is there a wxSoundStream class in wxWidgets?

Tags: wxwidgets, playback

I have read a book called ***wxWidgets cross-platform application development***(google-translated from ***《wxWidgets 跨平台程序开发》***), and in the book the author mentioned class ***wxSoundStreamWin*** and ***wxSoundStreamOSS*** for music playing and processing. However, till now I did not find this class anywhere else, including the wxWidgets Document Page.

So have anyone ever seen these classes before? Or do anyone have some other solutions to process and play music in wxWidgets?

I know the ***wxSound*** class, but it do not fit my need. ***wxMediaCtrl*** neither. I need to control the playing process, and provide an interface for users to operate on.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it was never part of wxWidgets.
`wxSoundStream` was part of an old library named `MMedia` that used wxWidgets.

p.s. a suggested replacement: [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/)